# Access variable from a Blazor component

Tags: c#, blazor

is it possible to get access to variables from another component in Blazor? In this case /Shared/client.razor.cs needs to get to access to var_1-var_3 in /source.razor.

/source.razor

```
...
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string var_1 { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string var_2 { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string var_3 { get; set; }

    
}
```

Comment: I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#capture-references-to-components) is what you are looking for.

Comment: There are techniques for passing to a parent or child component. If they are not related, use a state container and inject it where needed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly